# Detaching 'panels' or 'windows' cloud 9 ide

Tags: bash, cloud9-ide

I am wondering if there is a way to detach panels or windows of the IDE and move them around the windows desktop?  Lets say that I don't like where the bash 'window/panel' sits and I am working on a computer that has two displays/monitors.  Is there a way that I can click and drag that panel and move it to a more appropriate spot on the 'desktop'??  I looked in the documentation, but  only seen where I can 'slide' it left or right within that 'tools bar'.

Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now, there is no way to do this. You can only use the sliding function as you mentioned.

The best workaround at the moment would be:

1. Resize your Cloud9 window to span both monitors
2. Use the split screen function within Cloud9
3. Place some file tabs on one side of the editor and other tabs on the other side of the editor

Comment: Thank you. Atleast I know that I am not crazy and didn't overlook it.  So far, I have no issues with Cloud 9 IDE.  Just trying to get used to its work flow and where everything is.